# Convert/Save User Submitted "Time" in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where users select a time from a form

```
    <select name='hour'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='11'>11</option>
    <option value='12'>12</option>
</select>
:
<select name='min'>
    <option value='00'>00</option>
    <option value='15'>15</option>
    <option value='30'>30</option>
    <option value='45'>45</option>

</select>
<select name='ampm'>
    <option value='AM'>AM</option>
    <option value='PM'>PM</option>
</select>
```

I'm posting this information to a processing page where I need to save the time that the user submitted in the database in DateTime format. The data  will need to be stored in the database in the datetime format (2011-06-11 23:11:07) with the date being today's date.

I'm thinking that the data function will some how be able to convert it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough. Assuming the user enters 1:09pm, then:

```
$hour = intval($_REQUEST['hour']); // 1
$min = intval($_REQUEST['minute']); // 9
if (($_REQUEST['ampm'] == 'PM') && ($hour <> 12)) { 
   $hour += 12; // adjust for 24 clock, so $hour becomes 13
}

$timestring = sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', $hour, $min); // 13:09:00
$datestring = date('Y-m-d'); // 2011-06-12

$timestamp = $datestring . ' ' . $timestring; // 2011-06-12 13:09:00
```

There's other ways of going about this, but this is probably a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime) will convert a string input into a timestamp. Then you can use this timestamp and the [date()](https://www.php.net/date) function to format the date in any way you like.

You should pass it a string with a format similar to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" and it should parse it for you with no problems.